# Loop cut incomplete, skipping faces from a simple shape

Tags: modeling, edges, error

I'm having some problems with cutting a mesh. This is how the cut looks on Edit mode:

[image]

and this is how it looks on Object mode and how the model stays on Pose mode too:

[image]

any idea of why is this happening?

I've checked all faces existing, and also used the knife tool, but the result is the same. In some cases it even just ignores the whole loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Draw All Edges checkbox in the object properties panel.